# Creating an Update Trigger with Where Filter

Tags: sql, triggers

i'm new at creating triggers. I'm attempting to create a trigger which updates a the tblServiceOrders.GeneralSymptoms with tblAccounts.HotNote where tblAccounts.Number = tblServiceOrders.AccountNumber  and where whenever a new line is added to tblServiceOrders. Here is what I've got so far.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[HOTNOTE_update] ON [dbo].[tblServiceOrders]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE tblServiceOrders tblAccounts.AccountNumber = tblServiceOrders.AccountNumber

SET GeneralSymptoms =
    (
SELECT HotNote FROM tblAccounts, tblServiceOrders
WHERE tblAccounts.AccountNumber = tblServiceOrders.AccountNumber
    )
FROM tblServiceOrders
WHERE tblServiceOrders.SOType = 'BE Maintenance' OR tblServiceOrders.SOType = 'DD Maintenance'
END
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server (since dbo)...

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code, every time you insert a record, you will update the whole table, that is really high cost. I guess you don't really want to do that. If you want to just update the record you just insert, then why not before insert make the data ready and insert directly.

Comment: How would I go about making the data ready and inserting it directly? I'm sorry i'm really quite new at this

Comment: Please provide your table schema, your insert script, give more description what is your goal, then I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, it looks like your `UPDATE` statement is trying to perform the following:

```
UPDATE so 
SET so.GeneralSymptoms = a.hotnote
FROM tblServiceOrders so 
    JOIN tblAccounts a ON so.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber
WHERE so.SOType = 'BE Maintenance' 
    OR so.SOType = 'DD Maintenance'
```

This will update all records in the table with these matching criteria.  You might need to consider using just the Inserted record -- depends on your DB Structure.